# Adding migration after table created for cascading delete on_delete: :cascade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration, cascade

As the title suggests. I have several tables with has_many relationships and want to add a migration to handle cascading deletes within ActiveRecord as 'dependent: :destroy' has it's limitations.

The table I have an issue with causes an error of 'foreign_key_constraint' and this is due to the deleting of the parent record which should delete the child record but the order of deletion doesn't happen in the expected way. To rectify it, I need to add a migration to cascade the deletes so they happen in the right order. The thing I'm worried about now is that I have a lot of data in the table and if I add a migration like this

```rb
  def up
    remove_foreign_key :children, :parent
    add_foreign_key :children, :parent, on_delete: :cascade
  end

  def down
    remove_foreign_key :children, :parent
    add_foreign_key :children, :parent
  end
```

won't the removal of the foreign_key in the migration lead to removing the parent_id/child_id from the join and making the records useless? Or does ruby/rails have some magic that prevents this from happening?

Comment: Should be fine in PostgreSQL at least. `remove_foreign_key` and `add_foreign_key` should only operate on the table's constraints, they shouldn't do anything to the data. YMMV outside of PostgreSQL but it would be odd (and somewhat insane) for a RDBMS to change the data when adjusting constraints.